# What would be the weather inside the rings' shadow of a planet with 0 tilt axis?

Tags: weather, planetary-rings, axial-tilt

**The premise**

**·** super Earth (the super giant part can be nixed if impossible)

**·** rings system made of silicate, size is still to be determined (but the wider, the better)

**·** non tilted axis

**·** there are moons inside the rings but they're small (nothing like Earth's moon)

**·** high eccentric orbit

**The main question**

1)**The planet is supposed to be habitable (up to debate), since the planet has no tilted axis, I suppose the rings would cast their shadow along the equator all year around. So what would be exactly the weather in the area in the shadow if it's wide enough?**
There would be no sunlight ever, so I suppose it would be a very cold weather. Can life still grow there? Or would it be a total icey no man's land? Would there be some sort of micro climate all along the equator?

(the habitability of the area/biome under the shadow is also something I'm wondering. The planet is supposed to habitable, which I'm not sure myself. Given the gravity and the lack of bigger moon (therefore potentially having an unstable tilt axis and no tides).

**If such a planet is habitable, what kind of weather and therefore biome, would the ring's shadow bring on the equator?**

(I also want to apologize if my post was unclear as I'm not a native English speaker! I'm still learning the rules.)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Welcome to worldbuilding. Please be aware that, as stated in our [help], we accept only 1 question per post. That apart your premises are also unclear: how can an earth like planet be a super giant? It's either of the two. And, by the way, I am not aware of a super giant type of planet. Please edit your post to make it fit to our standards.

Comment: https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/asking

Comment: Thank you! It's way clearer to me now. I hope my error won't be seen as me trying to hijack the rules, I just misunderstood how it works!

Comment: What makes you think that weather is present only on habitable planets? Atmospheric phenomena known as weather are present as long as there is an atmosphere

Comment: I am aware! It's mainly to know how life could develop in the weather in the rings' shadow (and if it's possible) since this is supposed to be an habitable planet in my story. I am more focused on the weather part to narrow the question, but I want to know the habitability of such area due to the weather/temperatures.

Comment: I would say the ring would have little to no effect. Saturn rings are 10m to 1km thick, closest one is 7000km from the "surface". At this distance the rings would have angular size of 29 seconds, the Sun (from Earth) - 32 minutes. Sun is ~66 times wider, the rings would cover tiny part of it. The shadow effect would be negligible.

Comment: @D'Monlord This was not an outcome I thought about. I thought ~1km of rings would have made a shadow wide enough to have a climate impact. Thank you for your input! Would there be a way for the rings to make such an impactful shadow on the surface or is it scientifically impossible? (if they were closer, or wider?)

Comment: @Delkhii Axis tilt would make a huge difference. In this question rings exactly aligned with the Sun to make as little shadow as possible. If there is an angle, they start catching energy and cast larger shadow. I think it would make winters somewhat colder in parts of the planet, specifics depend on lots of parameters like angular tilt, geometry and composition of the rings.

Comment: @D'Monlord I see, thanks. Indeed the shadow cast if the pseudo Earth was tilted would be greater but also moving all year around. I admit that I wanted this sort of "shadow frontier" on the equator that would have brought another type of biome due to the lack of sunshine. But I guess this is scientifically impossible.

Comment: Not necessarily. 1km is a number from wikipedia for Jupiter, who said rings can't be 100 times wider? Sure, orbital mechanics and gravity seems to flatten it over time, but this time can be significant. A moon passed through Roche limit and was destroyed by tidal forces N years ago and now there is huge mess over the planet. It likely to gradually become cooler closer to the center of the zone due to air convection. Weather would be interesting. Cold air at ground level flows outside, hotter air enters, cools down, loses water. Could it freeze? Enormous ice wall in the middle would be cool.

Comment: I wondered if bigger rings could be possible! The story is mainly a mix of fantasy and SciFi, so it doesn't have to be hard scif fi but I wanted it to be as close a possible to something that could happen! Maybe if moons and new asteroids keep crashing at the roch limit? I wanted the planet to be a supergiant specifically because it's a planet that attracts a lot of celestial bodies into its rings, protecting other planets from it. (a bit like Jupiter is to the Earth). And yes I'd love to bring an ice ring/wall on the equator if the rings are wide enough. Thanks!

Comment: I also edited my question with taking in account what you pointed out!